# Is there a way to use ValueAnimator with a starting point mid-way within the range?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have image and I wish to animate its alpha in a repeating loop between transparent and visible. This is easy to do using ValueAnimator something like this:

```
  mValueAnimator1 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0f);
  mValueAnimator1.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
  mValueAnimator1.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
  mValueAnimator1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float value = ((Number) animation.getAnimatedValue()).floatValue();
        imageView.setAlpha(value);
```

That's straightforward if the starting alpha for the image should be 1,  and it would also be straightforward if the starting alpha for the image should be 0.

But in my case I want the starting alpha to be some value within the range specified within ofFloat() i.e. if my starting alpha should be 0.75 then I want the animation to loop like this:

```
   0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.0, 0.95, 0.75, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 etc
```

(values are just representative to convey the general idea).

Is there a way of using ValueAnimator where the range is specified such as 0 - 1 but the starting point is mid way within that specified range?

Comment: maybe add an animation listener. set the start value global and set it to the correct value after the first animation. To set it to 0.75. and in the onAnimationEnd set it to 1.0. Didn't try it, so it might not work

Comment: Why don't you shift your values so that 1.0 is first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mValueAnimator1.setCurrentFraction(startingAlpha)` to set the starting point, however `setCurrentFraction()` was only added in API 22.

Another approach might be to use an `AnimatorSet` consisting of two `ValueAnimator` objects, the first one with `ofFloat(1.0f)` (the value you want the animation to head to first), followed by another `ValueAnimator` that infinitely repeats between 1.0 and 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Animator.setCurrentPlayTime(fraction * repetitionPeriod)`; that is similar to `setCurrentFraction` but works from API 11+.